# SQL Last 6 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table containing one datetime column. I need to return rows for only last 6 months. This can be done by

```
where datetime_column > DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)
```

But how to extend this option if I want to return latest month beginning with first day of the month? E.g. I run this condition in the middle of month `(14/6/2000)`, the latest row is set to `14/1/2000`, but i would like to return it as `1/1/2000`. Any advice?

I tried some subqueries (max function of datetime including month function) but with no success.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For MS SQL Server, you can use:

```
where datetime_column >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,
current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Answer (score 15):

### In SQL Server

```
where datetime_column > dateadd(m, -6, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1)
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22330)

### In MySQL

```
where datetime_column > curdate() - interval (dayofmonth(curdate()) - 1) day - interval 6 month
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22117)

Comment: Do you have SQL-Server version? Somebody has edited my question from SQL-Server to MySQL from some reason I dont know. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one

**`where datediff(month, datetime_column, getdate()) <= 6`**

To exclude or filter out future dates

**`where datediff(month, datetime_column, getdate()) between 0 and 6`**

---

This part `datediff(month, datetime_column, getdate())` will get the month difference in number of current date and Datetime_Column and will return Rows like:

> Result
>  1
>   2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  6
>  7
>  8
>  9
> 10

This is Our final condition to get last 6 months data

> where result <= 6

Comment: You should tell people why this query answers the question, e.g. explain how it works

Comment: This actually is a very good answer. Too bad it's light on the details.
It will get rows within the current year. Whereas if you use some of the other answers you'll get prior years as well.

Comment: I tried this but it will not get the last 6 months of data. It will return the next 6 months range as well when your table does store future date.

Comment: to exclude future dates can you do something like where datediff(month, datetime_column, getdate())  between 0 and 6.

futures dates results are negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

`.... where yourdate_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tbl1
where
datetime_column >= 
DATEADD(m, -6, convert(date, convert(varchar(6), getdate(),112) + '01'))
```