# SQL Server Query Last 6 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, date, select

Every time I update the data I want it to only reflect the last 6 months of data. Below is my current query. Can someone assist me with this?

```
SELECT ar.[Report Date]
,ar.Facility
,SUM (ar.[0-30]) AS [0-30]
,SUM (ar.[31-60]) AS [31-60]
,SUM (ar.[61-90]) AS [61-90]
,SUM (ar.[91-120]) AS [91-120] 
,SUM (ar.[120+]) AS [120+]
FROM DBO.ARByPayer AS ar
WHERE ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien'
GROUP BY ar.Facility, ar.[Report Date]
ORDER BY ar. [Report Date]
```

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL, if you are using MS SQL Server. both are different RDBMS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Last 6 Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227964/sql-last-6-months)

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: @SalmanA my current query returns all dated results. I only want it to reflect the most recent 6 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this to your where clause, if I understand what you are after correctly:

```
and ar.[Report Date] > DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this clause to your `WHERE` section:

```
DATEADD(d, 180, ar.[Report Date]) > getdate()
```