# Fetching data for last 6 months in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the data for the last six months from MySql Database. The format of my data is yyyy/mm. I have tried using `DATE_ADD(NOW(),-6, MONTH)` in the `where` clause but gives an error.

Query I wrote is:

```
select * from attendance where date_add(now(),-6, MONTH)
```

This shows me the error as  "select is not valid at this position".

Comment: You should *always* use date or datetime data types for storing dates, never strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19227964/11878472 check the solution here

Comment: @nacho Thank you I will keep in mind from next time.

Comment: Are you using MySql or SQL Server?