# Adding a rolling time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the below. I added in the transaction date to only be pulling in data from 2022-04-01 but, I need to keep it rolling, so that it only pulls in data that is no greater than 6 months old as time goes on.

```
SELECT   entity_code,
         contract_category,
         manufacturer_catalog_number,
         product_description,
         manufacturer_top_parent_name,
         base_spend,
         Sum(base_spend) OVER (partition BY contract_category, entity_code ORDER BY base_spend DESC, manufacturer_catalog_number) AS running_sum
FROM
where    contract_category="PRODUCTS"
AND      transaction_date >= '2022-04-01'
```

Comment: First figure out the method to getting the current_date in your DBMS, then determine how to subtract an interval of 6 months.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, teradata, snowflake, sqlite, etc..)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Last 6 Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227964/sql-last-6-months)

Comment: @JNevill I am using sql server

Comment: Perfect! I have updated the question tags to reflect that. That should help pull in the many folks that haunt Stackoverflow that are sql server experts. I'm not expert, but I believe you want `transaction_date >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())` I'm sure someone will keep me honest if that isn't it.

Comment: Do you mean that for all of October you want the start to be the very first moment in April, and on November 1st you want it to switch to being the very first moment in May? Or you do you mean you want the start to be *exactly* six months ago, so in 5 minutes the start has shifted by 5 minutes?

Comment: Look up `RANGE BETWEEN`

Comment: In a comment you say that you get an error expecting `INTERVAL`.  That's not SQL Server.  Are you actually using MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To get the beginning of the month 6 months ago, you get the *end* of the month *7* months ago, then add a day.

```
DECLARE @start date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -7));

... AND transaction_date >= @start;
```